# <rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a lovecalc discord.js code, but it's showing me the following error.
Below is the code:

```
const Social = require("../Social.js");
const { get } = require("snekfetch");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    info: {
      name: "help",
      description: "Get help xD",
      usage: "",
      aliases: ["h"],
    },
  run: async (bot, message, args, level) => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    if (!message.mention.members.size) return message.response(undefined, "Ba-Baka! How will I tell you, how much you love someone. If I don't know who!"); //Response Can Be Refined 
    const data = await get(`https://love-calculator.p.mashape.com/getPercentage?fname=${message.member.displayName}&sname=${message.mentions.members.first().displayName}`).set("X-Mashape-Key", process.env.MASHAPE);
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setThumbnail("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/answers/3317000/3317487_1375024940496.53res_300_202.jpg")
      .addField("Lover", data.body.fname)
      .addField("Crush", data.body.sname)
      .addField("Love Percent", data.body.percentage)
      .setFooter(data.body.result)
      .setColor(0xFF0000);
      
    message.channel.send({ embed });
  }
}
```

Comment: check the value of `message.mention` is not 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Mention is undefined. It should be `message.mentions.members`

Refer to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) for further information